# how to delete active records in the database using code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Controller:

```
public function delete()
{
    $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->book_model->deletepost($id);
    $data['books']=$this->book_model->getposts();
    $this->load->view('showbooks',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function getposts()
{
  $posts=$this->db->get('books');
  $books=array();
  foreach ($posts->result() as $row) 
  {
    $books=array(
      'book_id' => $row->bookid,
      'book_name' => $row->booktitle,
      'book_author' => $row->bookauthor,
      'book_year' => $row->bookyear,
      'book_isbn' => $row->bookisbn,
      'book_publisher' => $row->bookpublisher
    );
  }
  return $books;
}

public function deletepost($id)
{
  $this->db->where('id',$id);
  $this->db->delete('books');
}
```

The problem is I can't delete the records. 
This is the error: `Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'`

```
DELETE FROM `books` WHERE `id` = 0
```

Comment: what you have used in your table is it is 'book_id' or 'id'?, in select query you have used book_id not id, so once check your db

Answer (score 5):

When you get posts the column name is `book_id`. When you delete is `id`. So maybe you need to change it to `book_id`.

Also `$this->uri->segment(3)` in this case will return null, because `function delete()` didn't have parameters. More details read [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

But I will make some changes:

**Controller:**

```
public function delete()
{
    $id=$this->uri->segment(3); // Try to write any id here, or in function put parameter
    $this->book_model->deletepost($id);
    $data['books']=$this->book_model->getposts();
    $this->load->view('showbooks',$data);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function getposts() {
  return $this->db->get('books')->result_array();
}

public function deletepost($id) {
  $this->db->where('book_id',$id); // I change id with book_id
  $this->db->delete('books');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your phpmyadmin and to find here table "books", click to "View" and you will get structure of table (fields), check, is there field with name "id".

At second way advise you copy phrase "Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause" to translate.google.ru and you will understand that it mean.

So, else: if you have field "ID" with Autoincrement, it can not be 0, check it too